# Confusion with interfaces in java

Tags: java, interface

Suppose I have a main class which declares an interface within itself, and I have two different classes(which are declared outside main class) which implement the interface. Here is an example of what I mean

```
class ClassMain{

        interface InFace{
            void implementMethod();
        }

        InFace inFace;

        public someMethod(){
            inFace.implementMethod();
        }
    }

    //class A implements InFace

    class A implements InFace{
        void implementMethod(){
            doSomeOneThing;
        }
    }


    //class B implents InFace

    class B implements InFace{
        void implementMethod(){
            doSomeTwoThing;
        }
    }
```

What happens when inFace, the object of interface InFace, calls     implementMethod from ClassMain? Is it going to execute soSomeOneThing or doSomeTwoThing?

Comment: Why don't you run it and see ? And the line `inFace.someMethod();` won't compile anyway.

Comment: was in bit of hurry, so did a mistake.. now edited. I want to know the concept behind it@sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Answer (score 1):

The code will throw a NullPointerException because `inFace` has not been instantiated.

You need to assign an implementation to the declared variable `inFace`.

This can be class A or class B.

```
InFace inFace = new A();
```

In your current example, you should add a Constructor to ClassMain to allow a customization of `inFace` from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Some common `Classes` which do different calculation in same named methods can be grouped with `Interface`.

Assume you have a list of InFace interface

```
List<InFace> faces = new ArrayList<Inface>();
faces.add(new A());
faces.add(new B());
```

As you see Two different classes can be added to the list since they implements InFace interface.

```
faces.get(0).implementMethod(); //class A will run
faces.get(1).implementMethod(); //class B will run
```